# User Scheduled Jobs in Azure

Tags: azure, scheduler, quartz, azure-scheduler

We have a requirement for generating reports based on a schedule. These schedules can be configured by the users for a report. Initially We were planning to use Quartz in a worker role and Create jobs based on the user input.
I'm not sure whether the Azure Scheduler can be used for this because I feel any jobs that could run at the application level could be configured in Azure but not the user jobs.

Please validate and let me know if there are any resources which I could look at.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Azure Web Jobs? 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs)

Can you please explain more about the nature of reports you're running?

Comment: I have to let users to schedule a SSRS report generation from the UI. I have one job which will accept report parameters and generate the report. I have set multiple triggers using CRON expressions on the Job. This needs to be moved to the Cloud and I'm exploring various options in Azure with which I can replace the Quartz scheduler or can I go with a Quartz Scheduler in a Worker role.